# Selecting Parent of a Class

Tags: css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.filter ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.filter li {
    float: left;
}

.filter a:link, .filter a:visited {
    display: block;
    width: 120px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #98bf21;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.filter a:hover, .filter a:active {
    background-color: #7A991A;
}

.active{

background: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="filter">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home" class="active">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

How do I add a red background to the `<a>` tag with an "active" class? Current code works with borders (kind of) but not with background.

Comment: use `background-color` since that is what you used earlier.  If that doesn't work add `!important` to the end of the property value.  That will overrule any other styling inherited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I love this problem, because it reveals an interesting thing about css.

## first

### do this

```
.filter a:hover, .filter a:active {
    background-color: #7A991A;
}

.filter a.active {
    background: red;
}
```

## the problem

css selectors are actually "prioritized" by importance, and that's what the problem was; css didn't care that your attempted override came after the initial styling... It saw the `.filter a:hover` etc as more important, thus the declaration was ignored.

This is because each selector has a 'grade' which determines its importance based on a point system. To be exact, in order of importance:

- **1000 points** inline styles
- **100 points** #ids
- **10 points** .classes, :pseudo-selectors, and attribute selectors
- **1 point** tags and pseudo elements, like :first-line, body and keygen

**So, `.filter a:hover` is worth `10 + 1 + 10 = 21` and the `.active` was only 10.**

Caveat: it does have quirks too. For example, 100 `.classes` are still not as good as a single `#id`